# How do I use get access to audio devices through the MMDevice API?

Tags: c++, windows-10, wasapi

I am trying to manage the audio streams with a program, but I am having trouble even getting access to an audio device. As a side note I am new to C++ and I learned coding in Java so I'm new to the idea of pointers as well as the ideas of the HRESULT and other windows stuff. On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/coreaudio/stream-management) page it says that I must first enumerate an audio endpoint device. I then did some more searching to find out how to do so and was lead to the [Enumerating Audio Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/enumerating-audio-devices) page. That page told me to use the [MMDevice API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/mmdevice-api). This page shows this code:

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
hr = CoCreateInstance(
     CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
     CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
     (void**)&amp;pEnumerator);
```

I tried to use this and the

```
(void**)&amp;pEnumerator
```

did not work, so I found some other code that used a

```
reinterpret_cast<>();
```

in order to deal with this error. But the problem that I am running into is that I am not getting a pointer. My code is below.

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator;

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);

//print CLSID to see if I get any ids
std::cout << CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator.Data1 << "\n";
std::cout << CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator.Data2 << "\n";
std::cout << CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator.Data3 << "\n";
std::cout << CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator.Data4 << "\n";

//temp variable to hold the result of the CoCreateInstance call
LPVOID *ppv = NULL;

HRESULT retrivedDeviceEnumerator = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL,
    IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    ppv
);
//I'm sure there is a better way to print and end the line
//print mem location to see if I am getting a result
std::cout << ppv << "\n";
//cast the result to correct type
pEnumerator = (reinterpret_cast<IMMDeviceEnumerator*>(ppv));
```

This code prints some numbers for the CLSID lines so I think that those are getting the correct values, but I am getting 00000000 when I print the ppv pointer.

Comment: Hopefully &amp; is not actually in the source code you tried, be careful copy/pasting code from a web site.  Very important to pay attention to HRESULT, it tells you why a function failed.  Declare the pointer correctly first, should be IMMDeviceEnumerator* ppv.  And pass it correctly to CoCreateInstance(), last argument should be (void**)&ppv.  Once you have a valid pointer, be sure to not use a C or C++ cast, use its QueryInterface() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively good code snippet [from there](https://github.com/zerofox/github/blob/830cdc3d54e4ebe78f831ca6c1834305ca532318/test%202/test%202/VolumeEdit.cpp#L25):

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
IMMDeviceEnumerator *deviceEnumerator = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator);
IMMDevice *defaultDevice = NULL;
hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice);
...
```